# How can I use Navbar link in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, navbar

I am trying to create a website by using Reactjs. I tried to create Navbar and on navbar, I created 2 links which are Home and Contact. When I click for example contact button, I can see the end-point on URL but on the page, nothing happens. I have already created Routes and Links but I really did not understand why I can not use Navbar's links. May you help me, please? Thank you in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {BrowserRouter, Link} from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
     return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to='/'>Sağlık Hizmetim</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/contact'>İletişim</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </BrowserRouter>
        );
 };

 Navbar.propTypes = {};

 export default Navbar;
```

It was my Navbar component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route,BrowserRouter,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Contact from "./Contact";
import Home from './Home';

const Routes = () => {
     return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
 };

 export default Routes;
```

It was my Route component. Also, I have called route and navbar component in App.js.

Comment: Try `<Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact}/>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not work:(

Comment: have you tried <Link> <li>? the other way around?

Answer (score 3):

You should use one only one instance of Router in an App.
Remove the **BrowserRouter** from Navbar Component and try:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {BrowserRouter, Link} from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
 return (
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to='/'>Sağlık Hizmetim</Link></li>
                <li><Link to='/contact'>İletişim</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
};

Navbar.propTypes = {};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: hey, when remove the BrowserRouter , I got another error which says "You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>"

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one instance of `<BrowserRouter />` in your application. Remove the one from `<Navbar />` and replace all the links with `<NavLink />` as follows;

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/">Sağlık Hizmetim</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/contact">İletişim</NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

Navbar.propTypes = {};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But when I change links to navlinks and remove the BrowserRouter, I got another error which says "You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>"

Answer (score 0):

In **Navbar** component, just remove `<BrowserRouter>`

**Navbar** component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to='/'>Sağlık Hizmetim</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/contact'>İletişim</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

Navbar.propTypes = {};

export default Navbar;
```

**Routes** component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route,BrowserRouter,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Contact from "./Contact";
import Home from './Home';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>     
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Hope this help!

Comment: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Comment: Maybe we should have only one `<BrowserRouter>` in our app. You should try call `Navbar` component in `<BrowserRouter>` of `Routes` component

Comment: I change Link's which are in navbar component to a href tag and now it works.  :))

Comment: I've just updated my answer, you can check it again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put below :

```
<a routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active">{{Your data}}</a>
```